# Xcode GPX icon Where is it located in Xcode 8.3

Tags: xcode

After upgrading to 8.3 Xcode I realize that the location icon is no longer there to add custom GPX location. Does anybody know where this icon was set to or is it completely remove.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The presence of this button is controlled by a setting in your scheme. Click on the Scheme popup in Xcode's toolbar, choose Edit Scheme from the menu, select the Run action, then click the Options tab, and verify that "Location Simulation" is checked.